# Scale bar for Iceland map not accurate

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, scale, iceland

I'm a fairly new user to QGIS and was trying to generate a map of Iceland. However my grid scales are not matching up. The base map I'm using is Esri National Geographic which uses CRS- EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator - Projected

The rough width of Iceland is 500km but according to the grid boxes QGIS generated in Print Layout its about 1000km. In grid properties they are set to be 5000000m x 500000m. And the scale bar is not accurate either.

Screenshots attached.[image][image]

Comment: don't use 3857 that far north if you want an accurate map.

Comment: What would you recommend I use?

Comment: any of https://epsg.io/?q=Iceland%20kind%3APROJCRS

Comment: please add an answer for future users

Answer (score 6):

As Ian commented,

> don't use 3857 that far north if you want an accurate map.

Appropriate CRS for Iceland can be found at https://epsg.io/?q=Iceland%20kind%3APROJCRS

List of recommended CRS for Iceland as of May 2, 2019 (see link above for updates):

- Hjorsey 1955 / Lambert 1955,
  EPSG:3053 with transformation: 6909,
  Area of use: Iceland - onshore. (accuracy: 7.0)
- Reykjavik 1900 / Lambert 1900,
  EPSG:3052 with transformation: 1994,
  Area of use: Iceland - onshore. (accuracy: 10.0)
- ISN2004 / LCC Europe,
  EPSG:5639 with transformation: 5327,
  Area of use: Iceland - onshore and offshore. (accuracy: 1.0)
- ISN2004 / LAEA Europe,
  EPSG:5638 with transformation: 5327,
  Area of use: Iceland - onshore and offshore. (accuracy: 1.0)
- ISN2004 / Lambert 2004,
  EPSG:5325 with transformation: 5327,
  Area of use: Iceland - onshore and offshore. (accuracy: 1.0)
- ISN93 / Lambert 1993,
  EPSG:3057 with transformation: 1952,
  Area of use: Iceland - onshore and offshore. (accuracy: 1.0)
- Hjorsey 1955 / UTM zone 28N,
  EPSG:3056 with transformation: 6909,
  Area of use: Iceland - onshore east of 18°W. (accuracy: 7.0)
- Hjorsey 1955 / UTM zone 26N,
  EPSG:3054 with transformation: 6909,
  Area of use: Iceland - onshore west of 24°W. (accuracy: 7.0)
- Hjorsey 1955 / UTM zone 27N,
  EPSG:3055 with transformation: 6909,
  Area of use: Iceland - onshore between 24°W and 18°W. (accuracy: 7.0)
- ISN2016 / Lambert 2016,
  EPSG:8088,
  Area of use: Iceland - onshore and offshore

Comment: Yes it may be better to use a different CRS.
However, *if* one uses 3857, it looks wrong that the scale bar and the distance tool happily show distances in  meters which are wrong by a factor of 2 or more. Another nice example is the building at the parking lot of the Nordkapp in Norway. That building is about 13 x 13 meters, but if you measure its size with QGIS, it's about 40 x 40 meters.
Now, I do understand that in these projections the distance factor is 1 / cos(latitude).
I'd propose to not use the term 'meters', but 'map units' for this kind of CRS.

Comment: And an even better solution would be to have on-the-fly correction of the distances, based on the scale at the map center.
Perhaps with some warning or indication (e.g. scale bar color change), when zoomed out, that the scale is not valid throughout the whole visible area.